# is this an instance variable of a reference type??

Tags: c#, arrays, list

what i really wonder about is this code:

**arrInt** ..... is an array of integers and
**listArr()**...is a dynamic list of integer arrays

```
arrInt = {1, 2}

listArr.add(arrInt)

arrInt = {3, 4}

listArr.add(arrInt)
```

result:
**listArr(0) = {1, 2}

listArr(1) = {3, 4}**

although i was certain the result was going to be:
**listArr(0) = {3, 4}

listArr(1) = {3, 4}**

this would suggest that each element of **listArr** is a strongly typed array that is an instantiated copy of **arrInt**
and not a reference to **arrInt** nor as a value that is a reference to **arrInt**, 
thus, you might think this a naive query, ~> are all elements of **List<T>** created as copies of objects?

Comment: The third line creates a new array object.

Comment: ... as well as the 1st one...

Comment: If you're asking about code, you should post code that compiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are all elements of List created as copies of objects?

No, they're not. You're creating new arrays instead of modifying the same one.

`arrInt = {3, 4}` is syntactic sugar for `arrInt = new [] {3, 4}` which is syntactic sugar for `arrInt = new int[] {3, 4}`. Can you see new array allocation now?

To get

```
listArr(0) = {3, 4}
listArr(1) = {3, 4}
```

you'd need to change content of initial array:

```
arrInt = {1, 2};

listArr.add(arrInt);

arrInt[0] = 3;
arrInt[1] = 4;

listArr.add(arrInt);
```

That would result int the same values in both `listArr[0]` and `listArr[1]`.

Comment: `{3, 4}` is not always syntactic sugar for `new[] {3, 4}`. `{3, 4}` is array initializer which the array type is the type of the field or variable being declared, whereas, `new[] {3, 4}` is array creation expression, the array type immediately precedes the initializer, or is inferred from the expressions in the array initializer. Typical example: `object[] arrInt = {3, 4}` (can be compiled) is totally different `object[] arrInt = new[] {3, 4}` (cannot be compiled)

Answer (score 0):

Without an extended conversation, it's not actually possible to know for sure what part of this sequence of statements is confusing you. But it seems to me that the crucial aspect of these operations that you're getting wrong is probably this: when the statement `listArr.Add(arrInt);` is executed, the thing that is added to the list is a reference to the object *that `arrInt` is referencing*, and not the variable `arrInt` itself as you seem to think.

Once the statement has completed, the element in the list has no connection whatsoever to the variable `arrInt`. That variable contains a value, which is the reference to the array `{ 1, 2 }`. When you execute `listArr.Add(arrInt);`, the thing that is added to the list is the *value* that the variable contains, i.e. the reference to that array.

When you assign a new value to the variable `arrInt`, i.e. the reference to a completely different array `{ 3, 4 }`, the variable itself takes on that new value. But since the element in the list was just the previous value of the variable, not anything to do with the variable itself, it's unaffected.

Comment: In other words, they both point to the same object in an independent manner, when the statement `listArr.Add(arrInt)` is executed? If the object changes then the change is reflected in any variables that point to it?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what "they" refers to here. But: if any _reference type_ object changes, then any variable currently referencing that object will _seem_ to be changed along with it. Of course, the variable itself doesn't actually change; it's just that the way the language expresses access to any object is through an expression referencing that object, and when the expression is simply a variable, in a way it looks like it's the variable that changed.